# Cleaning up a spill on a wood floor, without spreading the spill

Tags: cleaning, water

It is annoying to have water fall on the floor. After I try to wipe it, it spreads all over and becomes worse. It seems the only way to fix this is to wipe it a billion times.
I need a faster way.

I am using large cloths (don't know the type/brand, and don't have any photos).

Things I have already tried:

- Wiping it faster

This speeds it up, but my hand got tired.

Answer (score 2):

Mop it up in a circular fashion, starting on the outside of the spill and then moving in a cricular motion to the center of the spill, always keeping your mop or towels at the edge of the water. You'll push the spill inwards and force it into whatever you are using to wipe it up.